# SQL get top 10 records for each category: avoid subqueries

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift

I know there are many similar questions, but I am trying to get an answer that would ideally not include subqueries.

Need to find the top 10 Youtube videos for each of the 20 countries based on the sum of the views. 
The sum is calculated inside the query;

```
Select country, video, sum(views)
From t1
Group by 1,2
```

This is the simplified version of the query. When I tried to do Rank () and to use subqueries, the query took forever to run, so hopefully somebody will give me another idea of approaching this.

Performing on Amazon Redshift

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know of a way to do this without subqueries -- unless you use a semantic trick like "CTEs aren't subqueries" or "views" aren't subqueries.

Here is logic that does what you want, using a subquery:

```
select country, video, sum_views
from (Select country, video, sum(views) as sum_views,
             row_number() over (partition by country order by sum(views) desc) as seqnum
      From t1
      Group by 1, 2
     ) x
where seqnum <= 10;
```

Comment: When you sum the views inside the row_number function, do you sum the alias? So you sum the sum, or the original views?

Comment: @Nellyvel . . . Redshift may allow you to use an alias in that `order by` (this would be a SQL extension).  I modified the names to clarify the intent.

Comment: It didn't allow me to. Thanks, appreciate it